# Decide if sets are equivalent

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have problem with understanding how to solve such problems, I'd be grateful for explanation.

Let

$\displaystyle A= \{f \in \{ 0,1\}^{N \times N} : \exists l \in N \ \ \forall k\ge l \ \ \forall n \in N \ \ f(k,n)=1      \}$

$\displaystyle B= \{f \in \{ 0,1\}^{N \times N} : \exists m \in N \ \ \forall n\ge m \ \ \forall k \in N \ \ f(k,n)=1      \}$

Decide if $|A|=|B|$ ?

Comment: There's probably a typo in the second set: you have an $\exists m$ but no $m$ after, while $l$ is not defined. Anyway can you think of a very natural bijection between these two sets...?

Comment: Functions in $A$ are 1 for large enough $k$. Functions in $B$ are 1 for large enough $n$. Can you find a correspondence between the functions in $A$ and the functions in $B$? Is this correspondence a bijection?

Comment: I don't know what to do with the first finite elements both have value $0$ or $1$ so it's like characteristic function, so I have first finite amount of $0$ and then the rest is $1$ am I right ? but I don't have idea about bijection

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Think of each $f\in\{0,1\}^{\Bbb N\times\Bbb N}$ as an infinite matrix $M_f$ of zeros and ones: the entry in row $k$, column $n$ of $M_f$ is $f(k,n)$. Take a matrix $M_f$ with $f\in A$; all of its rows from some point on consist entirely of ones.

- What does $M_f$ look like when $f\in B$?
- Can you think of a familiar operation on matrices that relates these two types of matrix?

Comment: 1) I think similiar with difference to the moment when all rows are ones ?

Comment: @Mario: I’m not sure what you mean. If $f\in B$, it’s quite possible that *none* of its rows is all ones.

Comment: OK then I don't have idea

Comment: @Mario: If $f\in B$, there is some $m$ such that if $n\ge m$, then every $f(k,n)=1$. That means that in every column from column $m$ on, every entry is ... ?